# How to access the style property in a Native UI Component?

Tags: react-native

I am developing a  native UI component for React Native (this question concerns Android). I manage to pick up component props at the android side with @ReactProp [as described here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android#3-expose-view-property-setters-using-reactprop-or-reactpropgroup-annotation). The problem comes to when I am trying to read the regular style prop in the same way. It simply won't get into the function a wrote:

```
@ReactProp(name = "style")
public void setStyle(PickerView view, @Nullable ReadableMap style) {
    // never reaching here 
}
```

Any other property name seems to work. I guess it's because the style prop is handled differently. How can I access the provided style prop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the `style` prop in Android, you can use `ReactPropGroup` like so:

```
@ReactPropGroup(names = {"height", "width", "zIndex", "right", "top"}, customType = "Style")
public void setStyle(PickverView view, int index, Integer style) {
  //
}}
```

You can then use the value of the `index` to know which property, defined in `names`, was called.