# In React-Native Android, is there a way to get the height/width of a component from the ViewManager?

Tags: react-native

I am implementing a custom native component in Android for React-Native.

I set a property from JavaScript, and I receive it on the ViewManager (Java side):

```js
<View style={{width: 500, height: 500}}>
  <MyCustomComponent myProp="someValue" style={{flex: 1}}>
</View>
```

Because of `flex: 1`, MyCustomComponent view will have a height of 500. And because `alignItems` is `stretch` by default, it will have a width of 500

This is how it looks on the ViewManager (Java)

```java
@ReactProp(name = "myProp")
public void setMyProp(MyCustomComponent view, String value) {
  // How do I get the width and height of the view?
  // view.getHeight() and view.getMeasuredHeight() return 0, at least the first time

  // Logic that depends on the width and height
  if (width < 200) {
    // some logic
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

From the ViewManager, how can I retrieve the size of the `MyCustomComponent` view?

Comment: getMeasuredHeigth() function that native view offers isn't enough? I guess it will return a positive value since width and height are statically set. (also maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51921222/how-to-access-the-style-property-in-a-native-ui-component) is helpful)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, calling `getMeasuredHeight()` returns 0...maybe because the view hasn't been drawn yet.
Also, I think I oversimplified my question....the `ReactPropGroup` annotation might be helpful when width and height are statically set, but it isn't my case...let me update the question